# SQL - group by and allow references

Tags: sql

stackoverflowers.

I want to group a list by a field **name** and, as aggregate function, choose the most recent **date**. But I want to retain the value from a field **price** relative to the entry with that last date. Dates never repeat for the same name. Here is the example table...

> **id**         **name**           **date**           **price**   
>   1          Orange         21/01          1,99    
>   2          Orange         22/01          1,99    
>   3          Orange         23/01          2,99    
>   4          Orange         25/01          1,99    
>   5          Apple          20/01          2,49    
>   6          Apple          22/01          3,49    
>   7          Apple          23/01          2,99    
>   8          Banana         20/01          3,99    
>   9          Banana         21/01          3,99    
>   10         Banana         22/01          4,99    
>   11         Banana         23/01          3,99    
>   12         Banana         24/01          3,99

... and the desired result:

> **id**         **name**           **MAX(date)**          **last_price**  
>   4          Orange         25/01          1,99    
>   7          Apple          23/01          2,99    
>   12         Banana         24/01          3,99

Is that possible to accomplish this with SQL **group by** clause? Using a nested select is slowing things down, as I have a big, big table.

Comment: Ops, sorry, I forgot to mention. I'm using Microsoft Access. Sorry again! :)

Comment: No partition over ...

Comment: yup, I think partition over would be the only alternative to nested queries.

Comment: I'm afraid the migration away from access is the only option. Maybe, I'll try to fire one SELECT for each name taking the last record and measure the performance against the nested SELECT.

Comment: Access can handle decent amount of data. You might have to create index on both name and date columns (duplicates OK).

Comment: Or maintain a second table with last entries

Comment: I found out how to optimize (works in my particular database): the way records are inserted, for entries with the same name, newer records always have higher ids, so that the **ON** clause needs only a comparation to the max id instead of max date and name. This optimized from 10s (when using @zedfoxus answer) to 5s.

Comment: Very nice @EduardoPoço! That's great work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
select *
from table t1 
inner join (
  select name, max(date) as maxdate
  from table
  group by name
) t2 on t1.name = t2.name and t1.date = t2.maxdate
```

Comment: Great! Performance is OK! Never thought about inner joins, only about nested queries. This one opened my mind, thanks!